# PHP - Unable to convert SQL returned data to

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I am extacting data from an SQL Database to php, storing them in variables and echoing them. One of the fields is a date/time stamp which is in UTC, however when I try to convert it to a "Europe/Malta" timezone, the conversion does not happen.

**SQL Query**:

```
SELECT EventId, EventTime, Individual, Tenant, TenantName, DeviceName, Comment, InetDb.dbo.Individuals.FirstName, InetDb.dbo.Individuals.LastName
                                           FROM taclogdata.dbo.Event
                                           LEFT JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId
                                           LEFT JOIN InetDb.dbo.Individuals ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Individual = InetDb.dbo.Individuals.IndivId 
                                                 AND taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx
                                           WHERE (EventTime BETWEEN DATEADD(ss, -$timeframe, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()) 
                                                  AND (Comment = 'Reader entry' OR Comment = 'Reader exit') 
                                                  AND (InetDb.dbo.Individuals.IndivId = '$ListIndivId' 
                                                  AND InetDb.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx = '$ListTenantId')"
```

PHP loop for storing and echoing variables:

```
while($result_row = odbc_fetch_array($sql_run)){                    
                            date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Malta");
                            $EventTime = $result_row['EventTime']."<br>";
                            $Individual = $result_row['Individual'];
                            $Tenant = $result_row['Tenant'];
                            $TenantName = $result_row['TenantName'];
                            $DeviceName = $result_row['DeviceName'];
                            $Comment = $result_row['Comment'];
                            $FirstName = $result_row['FirstName'];
                            $LastName = $result_row['LastName'];
                            echo '<tr>
                                    <td class="CellContent">'.$EventTime.'</td>

                                    <td class="CellContent">'.$Individual.'</td>
                                    <td class="CellContent">'.$Tenant.'</td>
                                    <td class="CellContent">'.$TenantName.'</td>
                                    <td class="CellContent">'.$DeviceName.'</td>
                                    <td class="CellContent">'.$Comment.'</td>
                                    <td class="CellContent">'.$FirstName.'</td>
                                    <td class="CellContent">'.$LastName.'</td>          
                                </tr>';
```

I use the syntax below in order to 'Manually' convert the date/timestampin  $EventTime to Malta time, however this lacks practicality since requires manual updating:
`$EventTimeString = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',strtotime($result_row['EventTime'])+7200);`

After some research I've included the date_default_timezone_set function which should convert all time in my script to the Malta timezone, however when I echo $EventTime it's still in UTC.

Help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
J

Answer (score 0):

`$EventTime` is returned as a string and you're outputting it directly. I don't see any conversion. Try changing it to a date and changing the timezone. You could even make this a function:

```
function convertDateToDisplay($EventTime){
    $utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
    $date = new DateTime($EventTime, $utc);
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

An example of calling:

```
$EventTime = '2015-07-07 16:00';
$displayTime = convertDateToDisplay($EventTime);
echo "Event time is $EventTime Display Time is $displayTime";
```